# Training a BloomFilter on Spark with large dataset

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bloom-filter

I'm trying to create a bloom filter for a large number of strings from a dataframe - ~120 million. At an average of 20-25 characters per string the total data size exceeds our default `spark.driver.maxResultSize` of 1GB. I don't want to change the `maxResultSize` since I'll have to change it again when the size of the input data increases in the future.

Is there any way in Spark that I can stream the data from the dataframe in small chunks and train the BloomFilter by calling `BloomFilter.putString()`? I also tried using `Dataset.toLocalIterator()` but due to the nature of the source dataset I had to coalesce it to 100 large partitions, making each of those 100 partitions too big to fit in driver memory.

As a last resort I'm thinking of collecting the data into an HDFS file and reading it with a DFSInputStream but I want to avoid it if there's something built in in Spark.

Answer (score 4):

Spark [`DataFrameStatFunctions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions) provide `bloomFilter` implementation:

```
val df = Seq(1, 3, 7, 21).toDF("id")
val bf  = df.stat.bloomFilter("id", expectedNumItems=1000, fpp=0.001)
```

```
scala> bf.mightContain(1)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> bf.mightContain(4)
res2: Boolean = false
```

Comment: pls include the `import` statement in your snippet